# D3 Bar and Linear Chart With Multiple Axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, bar-chart, linechart

I'm working on a D3 bar chart that requires a superimposed line chart. I'm having trouble getting the line chart over it.

Final chart should look like this:
[image: This is what I would like the final chart to look like - note the yellow line chart.]

Here is a work-in-progress jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/t05qffo5/1/

Here's the code for the line chart I'm having trouble with. Just not sure how to make it work.

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {return d[2];})
    .y(function(d) {return d[2];})
    .interpolate('linear');

var linePath = svg.append('path')
    .attr({
        'd': line(chartData),
        'stroke': 'yellow',
        'stroke-width': 2,
        'fill': 'none'
    });
```

Any help getting the line chart to show up as in the image is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you're doing this for practice / examination, I would really recommend using something like c3.js (based on d3) for drawing charts - if you combine the combination chart and additional y axis examples from here the job's done -> http://c3js.org/examples.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to make a line function:

```
 var line = d3.svg.line()
              .x(function(d) {
                //so that the line is from the middle of the bar
                //here xScale.rangeBand() is the width of the bar
                return x(d) + xScale.rangeBand() + xScale.rangeBand()/2;
              })
              .y(function(d) {
                return y(d)+margin.top ;
              })
              .interpolate('linear');
```

Next is you make line:

```
  var linePath = svg.append('path')
    .attr({
        'd': line(data),//use the above line function
        'stroke': 'red',
        'stroke-width': 2,
        'fill': 'none'
    });
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/bL38srou/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome Cyril. Thanks!